# Adding Data Labels to Stacked Line Plots using

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Beginner python user here. I am looking to plot two line graphs stacked vertically and I would like to add data labels at key points in the graph. At the moment I am able to get the labels to appear, but not on the appropriate plot. See code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate

title1 = input("what is the project name")

with open(title1+"_rep.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

with open("Project003_rep.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
    data2 = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
#    print(data)

data = np.array(data)
data = data.astype(np.float)
data = data.transpose()

data2 = np.array(data2)
data2 = data2.astype(np.float)
data2 = data2.transpose()

#print(data)
#print(data.size)

x = data[0:1]
x = x.ravel('F')

y = data[1:]
y = y.ravel('F')

x2 = data2[0:1]
x2 = x2.ravel('F')

y2 = data2[1:]
y2 = y2.ravel('F')



#x = electrocardiogram()[2000:4000]
peaks, _ = find_peaks(y, height=0, prominence=10**-12.6)
#, threshold=10**-12.7

peaks2, _= find_peaks(y2, height=0, prominence=10**-12.5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,figsize=(18,6), sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax[0].plot(x, y, color='blue')
ax[0].plot(x[peaks], y[peaks], "x")
for a, b in zip(x[peaks], y[peaks]):
    
    label = "{:.1f}".format(a)
    plt.annotate(label, 
                 (a, b),
                 textcoords="offset points",
                 xytext=(0,20),
                 ha='center')

ax[1].plot(x2, y2, color='black')
ax[1].plot(x2[peaks2], y2[peaks2], "x")

#plt.plot(x, y)
#plt.plot(x[peaks], y[peaks], "x")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.xlim([20,150])
plt.ylim([10**-14, 10**-10])

plt.show()
```

This is my current output:
[Resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay0re.png)

Comment: Use `ax[0]` instead of `plt` in `plt.annotate`?

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks